# What file extension a php file should have if Content-Type is altered?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, http-headers

I was reading the jQuery Typeahead documentation from [www.runningcoder.org](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/documentation/), and taking a look to the [v1_user example](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/#form-user_v1) I was studying the source code from the tabs below the form.

As is obvious, **in the PHP tab** we can see all the 'data' stuff for then alter (IOW send) a `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and output `echo json_encode(array(...));` ("Everything seems to be PHP code").

Now, please go to the **Javascript tab** and *search the string* in your browser (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in most of browsers): `url: "/jquerytypeahead/user_v1.json"`. That `url` attribute is a jQuery Ajax option from the API (I think we all know what it is). The thing is **that is referring to a json file**, why? Isn't that PHP file we saw before **returning** a json content file?

I can prove this by going to http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/user_v1.json?q=ar

`www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/user_v1`**.json**`?q=ar` (note the json file extension)

**Locally testing**: I have some code returning `application/json` (the same as the v1_user example)
name it `test.php`. When accessing this script I **cannot** refer to `localhost/typeahead/test.json?q=something` but I can to `localhost/typeahead/test.php?q=something`. How??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that the Apache server cannot determine URL's based on what the script is returning for the Content-type heading. In other words, Apache has no way of know ahead of time that a script will be returning JSON data.

That said, there are a few ways to make Apache do what you want. Here are two that I can think of.

### Method #1

One is to tell your Apache server that .json files should run through a PHP parser. This means you would actually save your file as test.json and, when Apache goes to serve it up, it will execute it just as it would any file with a .php extension.

I am generally not a fan of this solution, but in some cases it can make sense. To make that happen, add the below to you httpd.config file.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .json
```

### Method #2

Another way is to use redirects to serve up test.php as if it was test.json. (In other words, when the user goes to test.json, you actually execute test.php) I personally like this method a lot better. However, it makes tacking down bugs a little harder because the file you expect to find doesn't actually exist. For most developers familiar with Apache, it's not an issue.

To make the redirect work, you can use something like the below in an .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.json$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Totally agree with you, Method #2 was the answer I was looking for (I should learn some httpd syntax).upvoted